# Symfony - buttonType - attribute with value from form entity

Tags: php, symfony

I was trying to build a form contains a button, which should have an attribute with baseId (eg. `<button baseId="1">history</button>`).

The problem is that baseId value should be get from entity for each row. I was trying as below:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
            $builder
                ->add('bedsoreBaseId', ButtonType::class, ['attr' => [
                    'baseId' => function($entity) {
                    return $entity->getBaseId();
                }
                ], 'label' => 'history']);
}
```

However, this results in an error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string").

What is the best way to access this property and use it as attribute value?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it directly in template

```
{{ form_row(form.bedsoreBaseId, {'attr':{'baseId':form.vars.data.baseId }}) }}
```

Or add this element to form on `PRE_SET_DATA` event

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            $form->add('bedsoreBaseId', ButtonType::class, [
                'attr' => ['baseId' => $data->getBaseId()],
                'label' => 'history'
            ]);
        });
}
```